# ExtJS: Select/highlight multiple items in menu

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a menu with a list of items.

I'd like the user to be able to select multiple items (without menu auto-collapsing). His/her selection should be communicated by highlighting the selected items. So what I need is:

1. A way to suspend menu auto-collapse on clicks
2. A way to highlight (select) specific items
3. A way to see which items are selected

Currently, I don't see methods in the API to do this, and answers from similiar questions are dated (~2007) for which the API no longer exists.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a checkbox menu, take a look at `Ext.menu.CheckItem`.

Comment: Ya that's what I ended up using :) -I'll give you the acceptance for your time :)